# Cannot create members with special character surname

Tags: coldfusion, postgresql-9.1, coldfusion-8, railo

I am working on a software where I cannot create a new member (ie person) with special characters in the surname. For example, the surname cannot be "O'Connor", because it contains a special character. But that type of surname can be added in database directly.

I am using ColdFusion and PostgreSQL 9.3. It works by removing the "cleantrim" function before surname in coding, but it is a temporary solution. Can anyone help me how we can do it?

```
                    '#Call.tSurName#', 
                    '#TrimCleanValue(Call.tFirstName)#', 
                    '#TrimCleanValue(CAll.tMiddleName)#', 
                    '#TrimCleanValue(Call.tPReferredName)#', 
                    '#TrimCleanValue(Call.tScoutingName)#',
                    '#TrimCleanValue(Call.tPostNominal)#', 
                    '#Call.tTitle#',
```

Comment: Use `cfqueryparam` and this will work. Your quote  needs to be escaped

Comment: Ouch, SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using [`cfqueryparam`](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) for all database inserts. Especially something coming from the client. Not only does cfqueryparam help prevent SQL injection it also escapes quotes and can help make your queries faster.

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tSurName#">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tFirstName#">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tMiddleName">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tPReferredName">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tScoutingName">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tPostNominal">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Call.tTitle">
```